# How can ocamldebug be used with a Batteries Included project?

Tags: debugging, ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocaml-batteries

I have a simple ocamlbuild project which uses Batteries, including syntax extensions.

`_tags`:

```
<*>: pkg_batteries,pkg_threads,pkg_batteries.syntax,syntax_camlp4o
```

`something.ml`:

```
open Batteries
…
let () = …
```

It is built for debugging with:

```
$ ocamlbuild something.d.byte
$ ocamldebug something.d.byte
```

Attempting to use the `print` command in `ocamldebug`, however, gives the following error:

```
(ocd) print x
Cannot find module Batteries.
```

This only seems to occur when debugging in a scope where `Batteries` is `open`ed.

What is the cause of this error? How is it possible to work around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make the Batteries includes available to the debugger; the `dir` command and the `-I` command line options enable this. Unfortunately, this is harder than it should be because `ocamlfind` does not support `ocamldebug`.  But you can do this:

```
$ ocamldebug `ocamlfind query -recursive -i-format batteries` -I _build something.d.byte
```

This will pass a sequence of `-I` options to `ocamldebug` to provide the include paths to locate the relevant modules.

Comment: Indeed, the first thing I did was check `ocamlfind` for its ability to invoke `ocamldebug` and came up short. I figured there was something along these lines. Thanks. Will confirm, and accept once I have.